# Replace a pandas dataframe value using a dictionary as lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas df column 'text' like so:

| text |
| --- |
| Aztecs |
| Apple |
| Mayans |
| Christopher |
| Banana |
| Martin |

I have a dictionary with integer as key and list as value. For example,
`d = {1023: ['Aztecs', 'Mayans'], 2213: ['Apple','Banana'], 3346: ['Christopher', 'Martin']}`

I want to replace each value in df['text'] to have the corresponding key from the dictionary. I am  confused on how to solve this!

My df should finally look like this:

| text |
| --- |
| 1023 |
| 2213 |
| 1023 |
| 3346 |
| 2213 |
| 3346 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an inverse dictionary and use `.map`:

```py
inv_d = {vv: k for k, v in d.items() for vv in v}

df["text 2"] = df["text"].map(inv_d)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          text  text 2
0       Aztecs    1023
1        Apple    2213
2       Mayans    1023
3  Christopher    3346
4       Banana    2213
5       Martin    3346
```